# ¿Están bien las colocaciones "correr parejo" y "acarrear algo"?

Tags: selección-de-palabras, vocabulario

Estoy leyendo un libro -- *Muerte y alteridad*, por Byung-Chul Han, Herder Editorial, 2019 -- en el que he encontrado usos de "correr parejo/a" y "acarrear".  Mi profesora particular de español me asegura que *nunca* se usa la colocación "correr parejo/a", y que el verbo "acarrear", en sentido metafórico, solo aparece en la colocación "acarrear consecuencias".  Por tanto, según ella, el hecho de que ejemplos contrarios aparecieran en el libro se debe a una mala traducción (el texto original es alemán).

Hay varios usos de la primera colocación en el libro, por ejemplo

> Un cierto existir para morir corre parejo con un cierto existir para
>   el otro.

y hay usos de "acarrear" sin "consecuencias"

> La muerte, que en realidad sería el final definitivo del yo, acarrea
>   un énfasis del yo.

Tengo confianza en Herder Editorial, y no creo que hubieran publicado una traducción mala, así que creo que la opinión de mi profesora es demasiada severa.

Con respecto al tema de "correr parejo", el DPD dice

> 2. correr parejas. Dicho de una cosa, ‘ser igual o muy semejante a otra, estar a su misma altura’. Suele usarse con sujeto plural (dos
>      cosas corren parejas) o con un complemento precedido de la preposición
>      con (una cosa corre parejas con otra). En el uso más culto, la
>      locución contiene, inmovilizado, el sustantivo femenino plural
>      parejas, independientemente de cuál sea el género y número del
>      sustantivo que funciona como sujeto, con el que no tiene que
>      concordar

Pues, ¿cómo se usa esta colocación? ¿Es el uso del libro correcto?

Y, ¿se puede usar "acarrear", en sentido metafórico, fuera de la colocación "acarrear consecuencias"?

Gracias por vuestra ayuda!

Comment: No entiendo "un cierto existir".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

La continuación de la [entrada del DPD que citas](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?key=parejo) dice (**negritas mías**):

> Pero hoy es frecuente, y admisible, usar en la locución el adjetivo *parejo, -ja*, caso en el que sí debe haber concordancia de género y número con el sujeto: *«Su gusto por los sindicatos blancos **corre parejo con** su repudio a la política de masas organizadas»*.

Por tanto, es correcto usar la locución "correr parejo con" con el significado "ser similar, estar a la misma altura". [Linguee](https://www.linguee.es/espanol-ingles/search?source=auto&query=correr%20parejo) tiene muchos ejemplos de este uso, por lo que la afirmación de tu profesora "*nunca* se usa" es falsa.

La entrada del DLE para [acarrear](https://dle.rae.es/acarrear) dice:

> 1. tr. Transportar en carro.
> 2. tr. Transportar de cualquier manera.
> 3. tr. Ocasionar, producir, traer consigo daños o desgracias.

Las dos primeras acepciones son usos en sentido propio. La tercera acepción es un sentido figurado, y **no está limitada a la palabra "consecuencias"**. Otros sustantivos con connotación negativa son perfectamente válidos. Por ejemplo:

- La ingesta regular de alcohol acarrea riesgos para la salud.
- La digitalización de las tareas administrativas acarrea dificultades para ciertos trabajadores.
- El acceso no autorizado a sistemas informáticos ajenos puede acarrear sanciones económicas o incluso privación de libertad.